# How Do I Find & Remove H1 From Site-Title-Wrapper?

Tags: php, customization, themes, pages, variables

Good Afternoon,

I am having difficulty removing a duplicate H1 tag, which is located in my Site-Title-Wrapper, per source code.

[image]

When I access "Edit Theme" and load the "site-title.php" I can see the wrapper code that appears in the source code, but it contains three variables, none of which contain H1 or are able to be found in the Editor Section.

[image]

Where can I go to remove the H1/ update it to an H2/H3?

Thanks!

- CD

Comment: To answer this question, one would need to have very intimate knowledge about the code of your particular theme. As such, it may be considered off-topic on our site, and would be best addressed in the official support channels for your specific theme.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the source code of the "Primer" theme, it looks like there's a filter available `primer_the_site_title_args` in **/inc/hooks.php**, which is wrapped in a conditional for is_home().  Something like the following added to your functions.php in a child theme should allow the title on the home page to be an h2 instead if you choose:

```
add_filter( 'primer_the_site_title_args', function( $args ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
       $args['wrapper'] = 'h2';
    }
    return $args;
} );
```